# Intel Graphic error: i915 [...] has bogus alignment

Tags: debian, suspend, intel-graphics

I'm using Debian unstable and I have a graphical problem after my computer suspend. My Xfce desktop is not correctly rendered on the wakeup, I can see my background through the panel (see screenshot)

[image]

dmesg log shows an error "i915 [...] has bogus alignment". Here is dmesg during the "suspend" action:

```
[44434.416880] wlp2s0: deauthenticating from 14:0c:76:6f:f2:61 by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
[44434.437532] cfg80211: World regulatory domain updated:
[44434.437538] cfg80211:  DFS Master region: unset
[44434.437541] cfg80211:   (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp), (dfs_cac_time)
[44434.437545] cfg80211:   (2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[44434.437549] cfg80211:   (2457000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[44434.437552] cfg80211:   (2474000 KHz - 2494000 KHz @ 20000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[44434.437555] cfg80211:   (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 80000 KHz, 160000 KHz AUTO), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[44434.437559] cfg80211:   (5250000 KHz - 5330000 KHz @ 80000 KHz, 160000 KHz AUTO), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (0 s)
[44434.437562] cfg80211:   (5490000 KHz - 5730000 KHz @ 160000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (0 s)
[44434.437564] cfg80211:   (5735000 KHz - 5835000 KHz @ 80000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[44434.437568] cfg80211:   (57240000 KHz - 63720000 KHz @ 2160000 KHz), (N/A, 0 mBm), (N/A)
[44434.531857] PM: Syncing filesystems ... done.
[44434.540113] PM: Preparing system for sleep (mem)
[44434.540324] (NULL device *): firmware: direct-loading firmware iwlwifi-6000-4.ucode
[44434.540338] Freezing user space processes ... (elapsed 0.001 seconds) done.
[44434.541893] Freezing remaining freezable tasks ... (elapsed 0.001 seconds) done.
[44434.543071] PM: Suspending system (mem)
[44434.543088] Suspending console(s) (use no_console_suspend to debug)
[44434.543385] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Synchronizing SCSI cache
[44434.543522] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Stopping disk
[44434.558538] e1000e: EEE TX LPI TIMER: 00000011
[44435.211800] PM: suspend of devices complete after 668.537 msecs
[44435.227791] PM: late suspend of devices complete after 15.977 msecs
[44435.229946] ehci-pci 0000:00:1d.0: System wakeup enabled by ACPI
[44435.230164] ehci-pci 0000:00:1a.0: System wakeup enabled by ACPI
[44435.230718] e1000e 0000:00:19.0: System wakeup enabled by ACPI
[44435.230726] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: System wakeup enabled by ACPI
[44435.243838] PM: noirq suspend of devices complete after 16.039 msecs
[44435.244332] ACPI: Preparing to enter system sleep state S3
[44435.263885] ACPI : EC: EC stopped
[44435.263886] PM: Saving platform NVS memory
[44435.263897] Disabling non-boot CPUs ...
[44435.264334] Broke affinity for irq 30
[44435.265847] smpboot: CPU 1 is now offline
[44435.266740] Broke affinity for irq 28
[44435.266745] Broke affinity for irq 30
[44435.266750] Broke affinity for irq 31
[44435.267795] smpboot: CPU 2 is now offline
[44435.268978] Broke affinity for irq 1
[44435.268983] Broke affinity for irq 8
[44435.268986] Broke affinity for irq 9
[44435.268989] Broke affinity for irq 12
[44435.268992] Broke affinity for irq 16
[44435.268996] Broke affinity for irq 21
[44435.269000] Broke affinity for irq 27
[44435.269003] Broke affinity for irq 28
[44435.269006] Broke affinity for irq 30
[44435.269010] Broke affinity for irq 31
[44435.270029] smpboot: CPU 3 is now offline
[44435.271974] ACPI: Low-level resume complete
[44435.272028] ACPI : EC: EC started
[44435.272029] PM: Restoring platform NVS memory
[44435.273248] microcode: CPU0 microcode updated early to revision 0x1c, date = 2015-02-26
[44435.273281] Enabling non-boot CPUs ...
[44435.273360] x86: Booting SMP configuration:
[44435.273361] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 1 APIC 0x2
[44435.274290] microcode: CPU1 microcode updated early to revision 0x1c, date = 2015-02-26
[44435.277098]  cache: parent cpu1 should not be sleeping
[44435.277332] CPU1 is up
[44435.277380] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 2 APIC 0x1
[44435.280573]  cache: parent cpu2 should not be sleeping
[44435.280750] CPU2 is up
[44435.280789] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 3 APIC 0x3
[44435.284081]  cache: parent cpu3 should not be sleeping
[44435.284425] CPU3 is up
[44435.292188] ACPI: Waking up from system sleep state S3
[44435.629721] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: System wakeup disabled by ACPI
[44435.630713] ehci-pci 0000:00:1a.0: System wakeup disabled by ACPI
[44435.630804] ehci-pci 0000:00:1d.0: System wakeup disabled by ACPI
[44435.631744] PM: noirq resume of devices complete after 17.691 msecs
[44435.632341] PM: early resume of devices complete after 0.553 msecs
[44435.645325] e1000e 0000:00:19.0: System wakeup disabled by ACPI
[44435.645806] rtc_cmos 00:02: System wakeup disabled by ACPI
[44435.649552] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Starting disk
[44435.865510] usb 1-1.5: reset high-speed USB device number 4 using ehci-pci
[44435.865588] [drm:intel_opregion_init [i915]] *ERROR* No ACPI video bus found
[44435.869545] usb 2-1.8: reset full-speed USB device number 3 using ehci-pci
[44435.977520] ata5: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 300)
[44435.977552] ata1: SATA link up 6.0 Gbps (SStatus 133 SControl 300)
[44436.125239] ata1.00: ACPI cmd ef/10:06:00:00:00:00 (SET FEATURES) succeeded
[44436.125243] ata1.00: ACPI cmd f5/00:00:00:00:00:00 (SECURITY FREEZE LOCK) filtered out
[44436.125246] ata1.00: ACPI cmd b1/c1:00:00:00:00:00 (DEVICE CONFIGURATION OVERLAY) filtered out
[44436.125328] ata1.00: ACPI cmd 00/00:00:00:00:00:a0 (NOP) rejected by device (Stat=0x51 Err=0x04)
[44436.126376] ata1.00: ACPI cmd ef/10:06:00:00:00:00 (SET FEATURES) succeeded
[44436.126379] ata1.00: ACPI cmd f5/00:00:00:00:00:00 (SECURITY FREEZE LOCK) filtered out
[44436.126397] ata1.00: ACPI cmd b1/c1:00:00:00:00:00 (DEVICE CONFIGURATION OVERLAY) filtered out
[44436.126472] ata1.00: ACPI cmd 00/00:00:00:00:00:a0 (NOP) rejected by device (Stat=0x51 Err=0x04)
[44436.126682] ata1.00: configured for UDMA/133
[44436.293577] usb 2-1.8.2: reset full-speed USB device number 4 using ehci-pci
[44436.386794] PM: resume of devices complete after 754.391 msecs
[44436.387345] PM: Finishing wakeup.
[44436.387349] Restarting tasks ... 
[44436.410524] i915 0000:00:02.0: BAR 6: [??? 0x00000000 flags 0x2] has bogus alignment
[44436.410648] i915 0000:00:02.0: BAR 6: [??? 0x00000000 flags 0x2] has bogus alignment
[44436.410735] i915 0000:00:02.0: BAR 6: [??? 0x00000000 flags 0x2] has bogus alignment
[44436.410986] pci_bus 0000:01: Allocating resources
[44436.411010] pci_bus 0000:02: Allocating resources
[44436.411064] pci_bus 0000:03: Allocating resources
[44436.411081] i915 0000:00:02.0: BAR 6: [??? 0x00000000 flags 0x2] has bogus alignment
[44436.411119] i915 0000:00:02.0: BAR 6: [??? 0x00000000 flags 0x2] has bogus alignment
[44436.411180] i915 0000:00:02.0: BAR 6: [??? 0x00000000 flags 0x2] has bogus alignment
[44436.411200] i915 0000:00:02.0: BAR 6: [??? 0x00000000 flags 0x2] has bogus alignment
[44436.411311] i915 0000:00:02.0: BAR 6: [??? 0x00000000 flags 0x2] has bogus alignment
[44436.425615] done.
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: I haven't checked but this is almost certainly either a harmless message or a bug in the driver. If this causes problems, upgrade or downgrade to another version, this isn't something a user can fix

Comment: @Gilles Ok. It causes only graphical non-blocking inconveniences. I will wait an update of the driver.